# character encoding html - utf-8 instead of latin1

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, web

I had a web page template that was basically just:

```
<html>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

But text in the body was (incorrectly) being interpreted as latin1 by my browser.  So I changed it to:

```
<?xml encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

This fixed the problem and the text was interpreted correctly as UTF-8 in my paticular browser (Chrome 17.x on Linux 3.x), however...

**What is the best way (most current browser-compatible and forward-compatible) to specify that the text in a html page is encoded in UTF-8?**

Comment: (The XML encoding declaration only works when you are serving your page as `application/xhtml+xml`, not `text/html`. And then it's redundant because UTF-8 is already the default encoding for XML.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
...
</head>
```

Comment: If you use HTML5 instead, then the `<meta>` tag becomes just `<meta charset="utf-8">` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would think, this HTML4 way:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
... etc
```

Cut and pasted from a web page of mine.

Comment: Additionally you should try and convince your webserver to emit the equivalent HTTP header.

Comment: Which HTTP Header is equivalent and what is the correct value of it?

Comment: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`, just like the `<meta>` tag says.  That is what the `<meta http-equiv="..." content="...">` is for - specifying HTTP headers in the HTML body.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put an `<?xml?>` on non-xml. Use a `meta` tag to specify the http content type charset.